# Save as PDF to Folder Script for Apple Mail

Tags: macos, pdf, automation, applescript, apple-mail

I want to add a script to a rule to auto-print messages as PDF to a specific Folder.

What I found was this: http://is.gd/acmsE but it doesn't work for me on OS X 10.6.

I already know the Save to PDF command and that you can create simple aliases in the "PDF Services" folder, but I need something automated for this task.

I searched the web the whole morning and also tried to write my own Automator workflow but couldn't manage it

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The AppleScript that can be executed does not receive any input. It's therefore not easily possible to act on any specific email.

I had some success by setting the new email's background color in the mail rule (something I don't usually use, and then using that as a marker which emails need to be processed from the AppleScript via Mail's API. Other options are flagging and moving to a specialized folder.

The AppleScript executing afterwards can revert these marker actions.

It's also somewhat possible to use GUI scripting for the PDF export, but I couldn't get it to work reliably.